# How to create thumbnails in wordpress with jwplayer

Tags: videos, thumbnails, jwplayer

I can't seem to get a good answer on their site. What's the best way to create thumbnails for videos uploaded to my wordpress site? Users upload videos from the front end and I started doing this with only youtube videos which was great because I could just pull the thumbs from youtube. So how can I can auto create them now and store them in a way that's not complicated. I tries using a the "video thumbnails" plugin but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did worked with the plugin [YAPB](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-photoblog/) (also possible with standard WordPress thumbnail but needs bit of code moding) and used this setting in the arrays of JW player.
It might be not fully automated but you can control your introduction image.

```
<?php if ($post->image): ?>
'image': '<?php echo $post->image->getThumbnailHref(array('w=400','h=276','q=95','zc=1','fltr[]=usm|30|0.5|3')) ?>',
<?php else: ?>
'image': '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>/img/no-image-video.jpg',
<?php endif; ?>
```